# What is the meaning of "imbibe the imbibements"?

Tags: meaning

> Though no statistics are available, it is probably safe to asssume that few of them regularly drop their butts and boogie to rock music, and that even fewer ***imbibe the imbibements*** which were easing the inhibitions of Lee Atwater`s audience.

Can anybody explain what "imbibe the imbibements" precisely means in the sentence above, quoted from the Chicago Tribune? Does there "imbibement" consist of a non material substance?

Comment: For the record, the original article can be found here: http://articles.chicagotribune.com/1988-03-08/news/8804050438_1_south-carolina-republicans-invisible-army-exit-polls

Comment: I can't find the word imbibements in the dictionary? Is this a made-up word?

Comment: @English Learner, sorry, I don't know. However [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/imbibement) has an entry for "imbibement".

Comment: @Carlo Although the word listed by Wiktionary has same form, it's a different (older) derivation using a more traditional sense of *-ment*.  The OED lists it as *†imˈbibement Obs. rare, imbibing, imbibition.*  I'd like to emphasize **obsolete** and **rare**.

Comment: Oops, that should read "has *the* same form".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, "imbibements" consist of a material substance--alcohol.

The word is a playful derivation of the verb *imbibe*, made using the suffix *-ment*.  Most often, *-ment* forms nouns that refer to an act or process, forming (for example) *enlightenment* from *enlighten*, or *investment* from *invest*; if it were used in this sense, then you could refer to an act of imbibing as an "imbibement".  However, this derivation uses a slightly non-standard sense, instead forming a noun that refers to *the object of* an action or process; in other words, an "imbibement" is **that which is imbibed**, namely, **alcoholic beverages**.

I consider this word non-standard, and I recommend you avoid it if your goal is to speak Standard English.

Comment: Yes, along the lines of *refreshments*

Answer (score 2):

To "imbibe" is to drink, usually used when referring to drinking alcohol.

I have never heard the word "imbibement" and I don't find it in a dictionary. I'm guessing the writer just made it up as a playful object of the verb "imbibe", so it would presumably mean "alcoholic beverages".

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that *imbibe the imbibements* is just a fancy way of saying 'drink', and 'imbibements' refer to 'drinks' (most likely alcoholic).

I couldn't find 'imbibements' in a dictionary, except [in Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=imbibement) (not an authoritative reference):

> Imbibements often refer to beverages, especially of the alcoholic type.